# Navigation Bar That stays over the TabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to have a navigation bar with a settings button on it that stays there regardless of which tab it is on.

Sorry for the short message its late for me,

Chase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is drag a UIToolBar onto your storyboard controllers and set the buttons and the actions you want there. You could make all your controllers extend form the same base class as to not have to repeat your code, as well as instantiate this toolbar in code if you find it more pleasing.

The problem will be when it comes to using navigation as the navbar will replace/overlap with this toolbar.

```
UIToolbar *myToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];

UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                            target:self
                                                            action:@selector(myAction:)];


[myToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:myButton, nil]];

[self.view addSubview:myToolbar];
```

Comment: I don't need to use navigation. I just wanted a place to put the settings button that looks nice and can be accessed from any tab.

Comment: Well in that case the solution I proposed will present no problem, try it out and let me know.

Comment: I edited my answer with a little code, the same can be done simply in interface builder and hooking it up with control drag

Answer (score 0):

In AppDidFinishLaunching:

```
Add Your TabBarcontroller (rootViewController) for UINavigationController
```

Now add setting button below is example in navigationBar

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];

navigationCOntroller.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

rightButton  will be visible throught application

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to place a navigation bar with a settings button that can be accessed from any view using a UITabBarController you can do something like this in the AppDelegate -->

```
YourViewController1 *yourVC1 = [YourViewController1 alloc]  initWithNibName:@"YourViewController1" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *yourNVC1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourVC1];

YourViewController2 *yourVC2 = [YourViewController2 alloc]  initWithNibName:@"YourViewController2" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *yourNVC2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourVC2];

UITabBarController *tabBC = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:yourNVC1, yourNVC2, nil]];

self.window.rootViewController = tabBC;
```

and you should have a tab bar with navigation bar on all the views. Now to place the settings button in the navigation bar, add this to the viewDidLoad method in your view controller where you want to show the settings button -->

```
UIBarButtonItem *selectBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(selectorName:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = selectBarButton;
```